# Hartl's Rails tutorial ch 11.4 Email in production: why am I not receiving an email? + Heroku error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, railstutorial.org

The final exercise of ch 11 is:

> Sign up for a new account in production. Did you get the email?

As far as I see it partially works.  When i sign up to the deployed website via Heroku  i get an error message

> We're sorry, but something went wrong.
>
> If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.

i see from the logs that an activation email has been generated but it never appears in my email inbox. i do not see why. below are the Heroku logs starting from the point where i create the example user2 with exampleemailaddress@gmail.com. Note: this is not a real email address but i tried with 2 real ones before. i am just using this email and user for the sake of this post.

```
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342658+00:00 app[web.1]:     <style>
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342659+00:00 app[web.1]:       /* Email styles need to be inline */
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342660+00:00 app[web.1]:     </style>
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342660+00:00 app[web.1]:   </head>
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342661+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342662+00:00 app[web.1]:   <body>
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342662+00:00 app[web.1]:     <h1>Sample App</h1>
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342663+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342663+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>Hi owen,</p>
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342664+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342664+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342665+00:00 app[web.1]: Welcome to the Sample App! Click on the link below to activate your account:
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342666+00:00 app[web.1]: </p>
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342666+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342668+00:00 app[web.1]:   </body>
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342667+00:00 app[web.1]: <a href="https://still-beyond-10331.herokuapp.com/account_activations/B9E9MkbJBlUEbYTLvf_kZg/edit?email=owenjharrison%40gmail.com">Activate</a>
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342668+00:00 app[web.1]: </html>
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342669+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342669+00:00 app[web.1]: ----==_mimepart_5a17af1a3f1f2_b2843f306332--
2017-11-24T05:33:14.342670+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-24T05:33:14.343060+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-24T05:33:14.342982 #11]  INFO -- : [a3094dfa-b0f6-45f5-862c-2c7f54404ad8] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1644ms (ActiveRecord: 1179.3ms)
2017-11-24T05:33:14.343765+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-11-24T05:33:14.343705 #11] FATAL -- : [a3094dfa-b0f6-45f5-862c-2c7f54404ad8]   
2017-11-24T05:33:14.343837+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-11-24T05:33:14.343771 #11] FATAL -- : [a3094dfa-b0f6-45f5-862c-2c7f54404ad8] Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication failed: account disabled
2017-11-24T05:33:14.343839+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2017-11-24T05:33:14.343895+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-11-24T05:33:14.343839 #11] FATAL -- : [a3094dfa-b0f6-45f5-862c-2c7f54404ad8]   
2017-11-24T05:33:14.346096+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=still-beyond-10331.herokuapp.com request_id=a3094dfa-b0f6-45f5-862c-2c7f54404ad8 fwd="212.174.5.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=1666ms status=500 bytes=1891 protocol=https
2017-11-24T05:33:14.343959+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-11-24T05:33:14.343909 #11] FATAL -- : [a3094dfa-b0f6-45f5-862c-2c7f54404ad8] app/models/user.rb:64:in `send_activation_email'
2017-11-24T05:33:14.343960+00:00 app[web.1]: [a3094dfa-b0f6-45f5-862c-2c7f54404ad8] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:25:in `create'
2017-11-24T05:36:54.633186+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-24T05:36:54.633027 #6]  INFO -- : [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c] Started POST "/users" for 212.174.5.195 at 2017-11-24 05:36:54 +0000
2017-11-24T05:36:54.639890+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-24T05:36:54.639786 #6]  INFO -- : [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c] Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
2017-11-24T05:36:54.639987+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-24T05:36:54.639917 #6]  INFO -- : [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"CQjYjjt1aXFsx4katSkk6obNnD/51iGtETU9pizfRLgcAlZtSITgl15njTWOY89jO72Vp9DiKstg2CmSKHYeYg==", "user"=>{"name"=>"example user2", "email"=>"exaampleemailaddress@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create my account"}
2017-11-24T05:36:54.787318+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-11-24T05:36:54.787201 #6] DEBUG -- : [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c]    (1.2ms)  BEGIN
2017-11-24T05:36:54.797518+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-11-24T05:36:54.797427 #6] DEBUG -- : [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c]   User Exists (1.7ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER($1) LIMIT $2  [["email", "exaampleemailaddress@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
2017-11-24T05:36:54.872861+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-11-24T05:36:54.872770 #6] DEBUG -- : [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c]   SQL (1.7ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("name", "email", "created_at", "updated_at", "password_digest", "activation_digest") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "example user2"], ["email", "exaampleemailaddress@gmail.com"], ["created_at", "2017-11-24 05:36:54.797954"], ["updated_at", "2017-11-24 05:36:54.797954"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$g6t4XvQPYYhVh3/tzNmd.ONZ9ldayN7KOfHW9cYLyOvEAqBtlLGZq"], ["activation_digest", "$2a$10$c.QMCwpe1zAJruyccsRQcecTF6co02uQ7J5/CLyX6UBCtCq2fnBpO"]]
2017-11-24T05:36:54.875122+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-11-24T05:36:54.875062 #6] DEBUG -- : [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c]    (1.8ms)  COMMIT
2017-11-24T05:36:54.881126+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-24T05:36:54.881050 #6]  INFO -- : [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c]   Rendering user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb within layouts/mailer
2017-11-24T05:36:54.883484+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-24T05:36:54.883420 #6]  INFO -- : [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c]   Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.html.erb within layouts/mailer (2.2ms)
2017-11-24T05:36:54.884432+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-24T05:36:54.884375 #6]  INFO -- : [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c]   Rendering user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb within layouts/mailer
2017-11-24T05:36:54.884974+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-24T05:36:54.884915 #6]  INFO -- : [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c]   Rendered user_mailer/account_activation.text.erb within layouts/mailer (0.4ms)
2017-11-24T05:36:55.036784+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-11-24T05:36:55.036677 #6] DEBUG -- : [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c] UserMailer#account_activation: processed outbound mail in 160.5ms
2017-11-24T05:36:55.180112+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=still-beyond-10331.herokuapp.com request_id=d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c fwd="212.174.5.195" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=558ms status=500 bytes=1891 protocol=https
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176384+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-24T05:36:55.176279 #6]  INFO -- : [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c] Sent mail to exaampleemailaddress@gmail.com (139.4ms)
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176430+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-11-24T05:36:55.176370 #6] DEBUG -- : [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c] Date: Fri, 24 Nov 2017 05:36:55 +0000
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176431+00:00 app[web.1]: From: noreply@example.com
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176432+00:00 app[web.1]: To: exaampleemailaddress@gmail.com
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176433+00:00 app[web.1]: Message-ID: <5a17aff7a020_62843f6c634b6@7e0cfe46-bf9e-4ef5-bd82-f0d5ef32afd2.mail>
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176433+00:00 app[web.1]: Subject: Account activation
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176433+00:00 app[web.1]: Mime-Version: 1.0
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176434+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176435+00:00 app[web.1]:  boundary="--==_mimepart_5a17aff78aa4_62843f6c633d1";
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176435+00:00 app[web.1]:  charset=UTF-8
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176436+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176436+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176437+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176437+00:00 app[web.1]: ----==_mimepart_5a17aff78aa4_62843f6c633d1
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176438+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: text/plain;
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176438+00:00 app[web.1]:  charset=UTF-8
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176438+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176439+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176439+00:00 app[web.1]: Hi example user2,
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176440+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176440+00:00 app[web.1]: Welcome to the Sample App! Click on the link below to activate your account:
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176441+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176441+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176441+00:00 app[web.1]: https://still-beyond-10331.herokuapp.com/account_activations/wNgvDOzoPpFYMMD-D_lFFg/edit?email=exaampleemailaddress%40gmail.com
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176442+00:00 app[web.1]: ----==_mimepart_5a17aff78aa4_62843f6c633d1
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176442+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: text/html;
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176443+00:00 app[web.1]:  charset=UTF-8
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176443+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176443+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176444+00:00 app[web.1]: <!DOCTYPE html>
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176444+00:00 app[web.1]: <html>
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176444+00:00 app[web.1]:   <head>
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176445+00:00 app[web.1]:     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176445+00:00 app[web.1]:     <style>
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176446+00:00 app[web.1]:       /* Email styles need to be inline */
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176446+00:00 app[web.1]:     </style>
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176446+00:00 app[web.1]:   </head>
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176447+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176447+00:00 app[web.1]:   <body>
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176447+00:00 app[web.1]:     <h1>Sample App</h1>
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176448+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176448+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>Hi example user2,</p>
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176449+00:00 app[web.1]: Welcome to the Sample App! Click on the link below to activate your account:
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176449+00:00 app[web.1]: <p>
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176450+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176448+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176450+00:00 app[web.1]: </p>
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176451+00:00 app[web.1]: <a href="https://still-beyond-10331.herokuapp.com/account_activations/wNgvDOzoPpFYMMD-D_lFFg/edit?email=exaampleemailaddress%40gmail.com">Activate</a>
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176452+00:00 app[web.1]:   </body>
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176452+00:00 app[web.1]: </html>
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176452+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176453+00:00 app[web.1]: ----==_mimepart_5a17aff78aa4_62843f6c633d1--
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176780+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-11-24T05:36:55.176724 #6]  INFO -- : [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 537ms (ActiveRecord: 31.0ms)
2017-11-24T05:36:55.176453+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-11-24T05:36:55.177316+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-11-24T05:36:55.177264 #6] FATAL -- : [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c]   
2017-11-24T05:36:55.177363+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-11-24T05:36:55.177320 #6] FATAL -- : [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c] Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication failed: account disabled
2017-11-24T05:36:55.177364+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2017-11-24T05:36:55.177407+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-11-24T05:36:55.177365 #6] FATAL -- : [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c]   
2017-11-24T05:36:55.177466+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-11-24T05:36:55.177425 #6] FATAL -- : [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c] app/models/user.rb:64:in `send_activation_email'
2017-11-24T05:36:55.177466+00:00 app[web.1]: [d4329f23-2e16-485a-aec1-4e24c92b4d5c] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:25:in `create'
```

EDIT: SMTP settings added below

```
config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  host = 'https://still-beyond-10331.herokuapp.com'
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host }
  ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => 'smtp.sendgrid.net',
    :port           => '587',
    :authentication => :plain,
    :user_name      => ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME'],
    :password       => ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD'],
    :domain         => 'heroku.com',
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Comment: I tried to register on your app using my email, but failed. Have you configured your SMTP server settings properly? https://www.railstutorial.org/book/account_activation#sec-activation_email_in_production

Comment: is it working in local ?

Comment: i just followed the steps in the tutorial. thats why i dont understand why it didnt work. could there be a problem with sendgrid maybe? @Vishal it works in development mode but doesnt send an actualy email, as is the expected behaviour. as i understand in production an email should arrive in my inbox but its not.

Comment: In development, the email should also arrive in your inbox .did you get mail in inbox in development ?

Comment: no. but the tutorial specifically says that the email won't arrive in development, but that the generated text will be viewable in the app logs.

Comment: I also learn from this book, you will get email in your inbox in development mode. but you need to configure smtp. Please check my answer in few minutes. you will your own or any test gmail account for send email in development and production, right ? . if you want to use send grid , than you need to configure send grid in your application

Comment: There’s a 500 error in the logs (which results in the “sorry, something went wrong” message), closely followed by this error message: “Net::SMTPAuthenticationError (535 Authentication failed: account disabled”. The account disabled part is interesting, I would double check that your Heroku sendgrid add on is set up correctly (you might have to confirm your email or something)

Comment: i think this is probably the cause i can't seem to log into the sendgrid account.

Comment: you are learning rails . right ?  is it compalsary for you to use sendgrid for now ?

Comment: sendgrid is what the tutorial suggests. i dont know if it is strictly necessary or the only way to send mail

Comment: You can send mail from your own gmail account. if you want to use sendgrid. than you need to learn how to configure sendgrid with rails app. and it is not necessary to use only sendgrid. you can use your own gmail account

Comment: Agree with @Vishal that you don't have to use sendgrid. But, if you want to keep following the tutorial and use it, I would try to find out why you can't access your Sendgrid account. Taking a look at the tutorial, it looks like your Heroku account needs to be verified (i.e., your cc on file) to use the add on. If you don't want to use sendgrid, the answer below has the settings you would need.

Comment: Agree with @inveterateliterate , than Owen should use directly sendgrid user name and password , because he is beginner so it will be better to use direct credentials instead of env variables. because he want to use that env variables. than we have to tell him. how env variable works. Owen please use this `:user_name      => Your send grid user name,
    :password       => your send grid password,` .

Answer (score 1):

Add Smtp setting to config/environments/production.rb:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'still-beyond-10331.herokuapp.com' }

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :address => "smtp.gmail.com",
      :port => 587,
      :domain => "gmail.com",
      :user_name => "xxxxx@gmail.com",
      :password => "xxxxxx",
      :authentication => "plain",
      :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Comment: but these settings are contradicting those from the tutorial. those from the tutorial should function correctly as they are.

Comment: what is your smtp setting ?

Comment: @Owen have you added `ENV['SENDGRID_USERNAME']` and `ENV['SENDGRID_PASSWORD']` on heroku ?